# Get totalsum from @onclick in vue

Tags: vue.js, shopping-cart

I want to make the {{total}} update when I click @addToChart button and it gets the game price from the vue array.

HTML:

```
<p> Total Price: {{ total }} USD</p>
<button @click="addToChart" :disabled="!game.inStock"
                        :class="{ disabledButton: !game.inStock }">
                        Add to Chart
                    </button>
```

Vue:

```
el: "#app",
    data: {
        title: "",
        about: "",
        games: [{
                id: 0,
                title: "",
                inStock: true,
                price: 59,



            },
            {
                id: 1,
                title: "",
                inStock: true,
                price: 40,

            },
methods: {
        addToChart: function () {
            this.cart += 1;
            return total;
       }
```

Comment: In your `addToChart` method, you return `total`, however `total` is not defined.

Comment: should I add a computed total method where I add the price of each items?

Comment: You could just add `total` in `data` and manually update in the `addToChart` method. But actually, reading your code, it just doesn't make sense. Could you give a more detailed explanation of what exactly you want to achieve? What is `cart` since it isn't defined either. Do you want to create the total price for every `price` property in the `games` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your `total` property in your data first.
Then just pass the price as argument of your `addToCart` function.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    title: "",
    about: "",
    games: [
      { id: 0, title: "Game 1", inStock: true, price: 59 },
      { id: 1, title: "Game 2", inStock: true, price: 40 }
    ],
    total: 0
  },
  methods: {
    addToChart: function (price) {
      this.total += price
    }
  }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p> Total Price: {{ total }} USD</p>
  <div v-for="game in games">
    {{ game.title }}
    <button @click="addToChart(game.price)" :disabled="!game.inStock">Add to Chart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```